# Как решить проблему с разметкой

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. 
В фон `RelativeLayout` я ставлю изображение, на котором изображен стол и река, ну и разумеется трава, облока и т.п. 
Добавляю компонент ImageView в котором изображен человек, ставлю его на стол - все хорошо, но, при изменении размера экрана человек оказывается не на столе а в облаках. Как быть в таком случае? как делать правильно?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/lug"
tools:context="ru.lolmail.MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
    android:src="@drawable/home" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/santa" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: код верстки прикрепите, пожалуйста

Comment: @АндройдАндройд добавил

Comment: Задачка у вас, мягко говоря, весьма нетривальная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам надо отображать одну картинку на фоне другой в одинаковом координатном положении при разных параметрах экрана, то вам надо вычислить координаты точки на экране, где должен находится левый верхний край второй картинки.

1. Устраивающий вас вариант используйте как точку отсчёта. Вам понадобятся ширина/высота экрана и margin по ширине/высоте второй картинки.
2. Теперь на всех устройствах, в коде вычисляйте насколько ширина/высота отличаются от стандарта и умножайте margin по ширине/высоте второй картинки на это значение

Так у вас на всех экранах вторая картинка будет расположена всегда в одном месте относительно фона.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению единственным решением является создания отдельного xml файла для каждого экрана [ссылка на описание](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/multiscreen/index.html)